# DES encrypt but Fortify report Weak Encryption on PHP 5.5.22

Tags: php, encryption, des, php-5.5

I want to DES encrypt and decrypt, but Fortify report say they are Weak Encryption
how can I solve this problem?

encrypt

```
    function encrypt($key, $encrypt)
    {   
        $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $pad = $size - (strlen($encrypt) % $size);
        $encrypt = $encrypt . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
        $data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $encrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);

        return base64_encode($data);
    }
```

decrypt

```
    function decrypt($key, $decrypt)
    {
        $decrypt = base64_decode($decrypt);
        $decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $decrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);
        $pad = ord($decrypt{strlen($decrypt) - 1});

        if ($pad > strlen($decrypt)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (strspn($decrypt, chr($pad), strlen($decrypt) - $pad) != $pad) {
            return false;
        }

        return substr($decrypt, 0, -1 * $pad);
    }
```

report
IssueGroup  Weak Encryption

```
    }

    $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_DES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = $size - (strlen($encrypt) % $size);
    $encrypt = $encrypt . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
```

and

```
    {
        $decrypt = base64_decode($decrypt);
        $decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $decrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $key);
        $pad = ord($decrypt{strlen($decrypt) - 1});
```

Comment: Well, how about using something *less* weak? DES was superseded by 3DES many years ago, but for new projects you should use something faster and more secure, like AES (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128).

Comment: Using `mcrypt` **and** DES is pretty much the worst thing you could do.

Comment: Actually DES was superseded by AES, that was the whole point of the encryption algorithm competition. 3DES was a stop-gap measure and even with a full 168-bit key only has 112-bit security.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

DES *is*, in fact, weak encryption. It was publicly broken in the 90's in under 24 hours - the problem is that its key is too short, it's possible to crack it with a brute-force attack. It's no longer suitable as a defense against motivated attackers. There are a number of better options available, such as 3DES, AES, and Twofish.

**Edit:** 3DES is better than DES in the sense that it's significantly more secure (but still less secure than AES), but its performance is of necessity significantly worse than AES, DES, or Twofish (because you're essentially applying DES three times). 3DES is rarely used for new implementations.

Comment: No, 3DES and Twofish are not particularly good options, AES should be used unless there are well understood reasons to choose another  symmetric key encryption algorithm.

Comment: I agree, 3DES is a poor choice (particularly because it's relatively slow). It's still significantly better than single DES though security-wise, I'll edit to make that clearer in my post. I don't see a problem with Twofish though, it was an AES finalist and it's still considered highly secure (and is likely to remain secure for a long time).

Comment: I don't dislike Twofish and am aware of its history and author. Two issues with Twofish: 1. It has has less peer review, review essentially ended the it was not chosen for AES. 2. From an interoperability standpoint there are many systems that do not support it well, the support may be be inferior speed wise and certification wise. An example is iOS, AES has hardware cryptographic support and that provideds a 500 to 1000 times speed improvement, CryptoSwift is an example of this. Also on iOS and macOS the AES version is FIPS 140-2 certified (implementation review).

Comment: Fair enough, those are good points. I'm not convinced that there's a practical security improvement by using AES over Twofish from a purely algorithmic perspective (actually, all of the AES finalists seem to have good security characteristics but you don't hear much about Serpent or MARS these days for whatever reason), neither has a known practical attack as of now (and I think it'll be quite awhile before there is one), but AES does seem to have better library support and peer review.